# Solving Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Why does this always return  9 plus the actual value of the answer. So for example, for the number 1234, the answer is 1 yet the function returns 10. I don't know why this is the case, I'm pretty sure it is something to do with recursion but I have no idea.

```
int fun(int n) {
    if (n <= 9) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fun(n / 10) + (n % 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's convinced you that the answer *should* be 1?

Comment: It looks like this method sums up all of the digits of the number, which is `10`.  What is it supposed to do to return `1`?

Comment: I can't see the problem here, the output is fine.It returns the sum of the digits as it is mentioned above.

Comment: The method returns the sum of digits. By your question, it seems like you want it to return a single digit, i.e. if the sum is greater than 9, sum the digits again and again until you get only a digit. So you need to wrap it with either a loop or another recursive method.

Comment: I understand where I went wrong, I was looking at it like return fun((n/10)+(n%10)) instead of fun(n/10) +  (n%10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Makoto stated, it's unclear why you believe the answer should be 1.  However, if you do the recursion analysis you get the following:

```
fn(1234) = fn(123) + 4 = 10
fn(123)  = fn(12) + 3  = 6
fn(12)   = fn(1) + 2   = 3
fn(1)    = 1
```

therefore, using simple substitution, you get:

```
fn(1234) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit Pshemo; I was in the midst of fixing it, tried to commit, but got a message stating that you'd already edited.  Thanks for the super fast response!!  :-)